# strange issue with user_meta + json_encode/decode

Tags: user-meta, json

I'm getting some user input and storing it as JSON string in user meta (kind of array of JSON objects). If user input has a single quote (`'`) the result of `json_decode` is `null`. How do I get the actual values?

```
$records = array();
$record = array("abc" => "xy\'z"); // original code: array("abc" => $_POST['fieldname']);
$records[] = $record;
$encoded = json_encode($records);

var_dump( json_decode( $encoded ) ); // returns array

update_user_meta($user_id, 'temp_data', $encoded ); // I can see encoded string stored in wp_usermeta
var_dump( json_decode( get_user_meta($user_id, 'temp_data', true) ) ); // returns null
```